# Citroen C3 2006

Tags: engine, gasoline, cranks-wont-run

I have a Citroen C3 2006 petrol engine that for some reason it never been used from new. It only have 33 km, it was stood all this time, obviously without battery.
Now we are trying to start it but it is only turning but not starting.
so we already changed inlet, injectors, all spark plugs, fuel pump.
spark is coming well fuel is coming as well and we made a compression test and is making around 9 and 10 psi
Now we noticed that when opening and locking the car from the door lock it is locking and opening only the drivers door

Answer (score 0):

Ok, 9-10 psi, are you SURE about that?  If so, this engine has a major problem.  Generally the compression should be 90-100 psi or more depending on the engine.  But you're nowhere close to that.  Are you sure you're using the compression gauge properly?

For an engine to run you need air, fuel, compression, and spark.  You've addressed fuel and spark, and I'm assuming you have air.  But without compression it will not run at all.

Just guessing here but I'm thinking you have stuck valves and/or rust in the cylinder bores which have ruined the rings.

Comment: that what i was thinking at the beginning but than i noticed that it is not locking and unlocking, so it mixed me up because i am not an expert on electric

Comment: and about the compression i tested it again with a new compression gauge and it is marking +-7 bar on all 4 pistons

Comment: 7 bar (I'm not sure about +-7 though) is just over 100 psi.  Perhaps low but I'm not sure what's normal for that model.  I think it's high enough to support combustion though.

Comment: Are you sure fuel is getting into the engine?